# r openxlsx numFmt - struggling with excel number format

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am trying to save a R dataframe to excel with openxlsx. Some columns contain text, other contain numbers.

I have borrowed below scrip from elsewhere (thanks) and it works in principle. Below shown is the case with a very small example dataframe.
My problem is the numberformat to put with numFmt.
In my orignal data I have a mix of intergers and decimal numbers in a column, the R data type is numeric.
When I export I want these to show "as they are" in excel.

```
library("openxlsx")  

df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c"), Value = c(12345, 12.52, 0.0001))

# Create workbook & sheet:
wb    <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
sheet <- openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "test")

# Create the cell style
textstyle <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt = "@")
numericstyle <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt = "######.######")

# Assign df to workbook
openxlsx::writeDataTable(wb = wb, sheet = "test", x = df)

# First identify the range of the 'text cells':
textcells <- expand.grid(row = c(1:(nrow(df)+1)), col = c(1))
numericcells <- expand.grid(row=c(1:(nrow(df)+1)), col = c(2))

# Then assign 'textstyle' to the 'textcells-range':
openxlsx::addStyle(wb = wb, sheet = "test", 
                   rows = textcells$row, cols = textcells$col, 
                   style = textstyle) 

openxlsx::addStyle(wb = wb, sheet = "test", 
                   rows = numericcells$row, cols = numericcells$col, 
                   style = numericstyle) 

# Save the workbook
openXL(wb)
```

I cannot find the right numFmt to put into the line
`numericstyle <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt = "######.######")`

12345 should show as 12345
12.52 should show as 12.52
0.001 should show as 0.001

The above "#####.#####" gives me in Excel:
12345.
12.52
.0001

I dont want the comma after the integer(s), and the .0001 shoudl show as 0.0001.
When I export I want the numebers to show "as they are in R" in excel.

I have tried various options, trying to google examples etc...

numFmt = "#.0"
gives me in Excel:
12345.0
12.5
.0

Appologies if this is a stupid question or if this is answered elsewhere... could not find a solution for me.

P.S: I am using the latest R 4.3.1, the latest RStudio 2023.06.0 Build 421 and latest openxlsx package (4.2.5.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `numFmt = "GENERAL"`

```r
library("openxlsx")  

df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c"), Value = c(12345, 12.52, 0.0001))

# Create workbook & sheet:
wb    <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
sheet <- openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "test")


textstyle <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt = "TEXT")
numericstyle <- openxlsx::createStyle(numFmt = "GENERAL")


# Assign df to workbook
openxlsx::writeDataTable(wb = wb, sheet = "test", x = df)

# First identify the range of the 'text cells':
textcells <- expand.grid(row = c(1:(nrow(df)+1)), col = c(1))
numericcells <- expand.grid(row=c(1:(nrow(df)+1)), col = c(2))

# Then assign 'textstyle' to the 'textcells-range':
openxlsx::addStyle(wb = wb, sheet = "test", 
                   rows = textcells$row, cols = textcells$col, 
                   style = textstyle) 

openxlsx::addStyle(wb = wb, sheet = "test", 
                   rows = numericcells$row, cols = numericcells$col, 
                   style = numericstyle) 

# Save the workbook
openXL(wb)
```

Which give you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Peter .... I feel stupid now for even asking ....